# Join Table with oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I am newbie for Oracle SQL.  I wish to join 2 tables.

In TABLE 1  two tables had been join with the below presentation

[image: image of table 1]

Here is the sql script for TABLE 1:

```
select a.ID,
       a.CLASSIFICATION_CODE,
       a. CATEGORY_CODE
        from a, b
        where locality = 'xxx'   
        and a.DIV = b.DIV
        and a.TYPE = b.TYPE
        and a.DIST = b.DIST
        and a.BS = b.BS
        and a.LOT = b.LOT;
```

TABLE 2

[image: image of table 2]

Here is the sql script for TABLE 2:

```
select CODE_TYPE,CODE_1,CODE_DESC from PUBCODE01
        where PUBCODE01.code_type IN ('LCL','LCA');
```

TABLE 3 (the table for final result after join 3 tables)

[image: image of table 3]

I need help on how could I combined the two sql script in order to produce the TABLE 3 presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to join twice the same table, based on the code_ty; for example:

```
SQL> with query1(id, classification_code, category_code) as(
  2      select 123, 1, 3 from dual union all
  3      select 456, 2, 4 from dual union all
  4      select 789, 1, 3 from dual
  5  ),
  6  query2(code_type, code_1, code_desc) as (
  7      select 'LCL', 1, 'TOMATOES'  from dual union all
  8      select 'LCL', 2, 'DURIAN'    from dual union all
  9      select 'LCA', 3, 'VEGETABLE' from dual union all
 10      select 'LCA', 4, 'FRUITS'    from dual
 11  )
 12  select id, LCL.code_desc, LCA.code_desc
 13  from query1
 14      inner join query2 LCL
 15          on(LCL.code_1 = query1.classification_code)
 16      inner join query2 LCA
 17          on(LCA.code_1 = query1.category_code);

        ID CODE_DESC CODE_DESC
---------- --------- ---------
       123 TOMATOES  VEGETABLE
       789 TOMATOES  VEGETABLE
       456 DURIAN    FRUITS
```

or even the following, depending on what your data can be:

```
select id, LCL.code_desc, LCA.code_desc
from query1
    inner join query2 LCL
        on(LCL.code_1 = query1.classification_code
           and LCL.code_type = 'LCL')
    inner join query2 LCA
        on(LCA.code_1 = query1.category_code
           and LCA.code_type = 'LCA')
```

As an aside, you should better use ANSI join; your query should be:

```
select a.ID,
       a.CLASSIFICATION_CODE,
       a. CATEGORY_CODE
from a
    inner join  b
      on(
             a.DIV  = b.DIV
         and a.TYPE = b.TYPE
         and a.DIST = b.DIST
         and a.BS   = b.BS
         and a.LOT  = b.LOT
         )
where locality = 'xxx'
```

Comment: Hi, Aleksej.  Is there any way to simplified to pass in query1 as variable in sql statement?  Because I have a very long query1 sql scripts.  And is that possible to put the query1 into array?

Answer (score 0):

Tomatoes are a fruit, please research your produce before posting.